# .vimrc action onclose

Tags: bash, vim

is it possible to use something like an "vim-close/exit"-Event to execute some last commands before vim quits?

I use this lines in my config, to let vim set my screen-title:

> if $TERM=='xterm-color'
>
> ```
>  exe "set title titlestring=vim:%t"
>  exe "set title t_ts=\<ESC>k t_fs=\<ESC>\\"
> ```
>
> endif

but when i close vim, the title is set to: "Thanks for flying Vim" (whereever that comes from...)

My goal is, to reset the title to the old one - if possible - and if not - set is to something like "bash" with that "exe"-Command

So.. is there something like an "close-event" in vim?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a "close-event" -- actually two of them.
To quote vim's **:help {event}**:

```
            Startup and exit
|VimEnter|              after doing all the startup stuff
|GUIEnter|              after starting the GUI successfully
|TermResponse|    after the terminal response to |t_RV| is received

|VimLeavePre|        before exiting Vim, before writing the viminfo file
|VimLeave|              before exiting Vim, after writing the viminfo file
```

You're after the **VimLeave**-Event.
A working sample looks like this:

```
function! ResetTitle()
    " disable vim's ability to set the title
    exec "set title t_ts='' t_fs=''"

    " and restore it to 'bash'
    exec ":!echo -e '\033kbash\033\\'\<CR>"
endfunction

au VimLeave * silent call ResetTitle()
```

In addition you can use *v:dying* to catch abnormal exit cases.

Comment: big big thanx... bit i've found an cool alternative after the VimLeave didnt work:

let &titleold=substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, "~", '')

vim seems to have an titleold, which it restores on exit :)

Now it sets ~/my/path 

Thats cool :)

Comment: @Beerweasle your comment is not entirely correct, it should be `let &titleold=substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, "~", "")`
 But thanks a lot for the idea!!